# Silent Print with Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, winapi

I have a desktop application that needs to print HTML files. I can launch Internet Explorer with the printto verb from Shell Execute and it will print the file, the problem is it always displays the print settings dialog box. Is there any way to get it to print without the dialog?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5184262/50447