# How can I print HTML files to a specified printer using shellexecute?

Tags: c#, printing, shellexecute

I have an application that has records that can have a number of attachments associated to them, which may be a collection of JPG, TIF, PDF or HTM files (theoretically this list is arbitrary, and these are the most typical types).

One of the actions I need to be able to do is to allow these to be printed **en mass** to a specific printer.

For most file types, I can emulate the shell and perform the same action as had they dragged the file and dropped it onto a printer in explorer, by using the "PrintTo" verb, and using ShellExecute (via `ProcessStartInfo`); however, I've been scratching my head for a while wondering why this wasn't working for HTM files - instead it always prompts to select a printer for each file, even though the registry settings appear to be there for it.

It is when I went back to first principles, and checked to see if the shell behaves "properly" when I discovered that it behaves the same way (so, lets say you drag and drop any old HTML file onto a printer in explorer, it always prompts to print, defaulting the printer to be your default printer, *even if that isn't the printer you dropped the file onto*)

Now, it [appears this behaviour was introduced in IE7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vclanguage/thread/9eafa428-b279-42fb-aa2a-fe790b4a81fb) (whether intentionally, or not, I'm unsure); but is there any way of getting this to work as expected?

**EDIT:** This is for an internal application, so it would be permissible to fix up the registry **if** that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the webbrowser control and call the .Print() method.  I just tested it and it went right to my default printer without prompting me.  I know that might not be ideal, but I think it should get the job done.

Comment: It would be better if I could choose the printer; Seems like a big dirty hack, but it might be what I'll have to do...

Comment: The webbrowser control also has a ShowPrintDialog method to allow you to select a printer.